# Why does the first Date String return false?

Tags: c#, validation, date, date-format

I'm trying to parse strings to see if they are valid dates.
I'm using few cultures and formats to cover different variations of the dates.

Functionality wise, the code below seems to work fine, but I can't grasp why the first string returns 'False'. 
Is it not a valid Date string of ***MM-dd-yyyy*** format?.

```
public class Program
        {

           public static CultureInfo frc = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
            public static CultureInfo usc = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            public static CultureInfo gbc = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            public static CultureInfo inc = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
            public static string[] dateFormats = { "d-M-yy", "dd-MM-yyyy","d-M-yyyy", "dd MMMM yyyy", "dMyy", "dMyyyy", "d/M/yy", "d/M/yyyy" };
            public static void Main()
            {
                bool isValidDate = false;

                string[] listOfDates = { "10-23-2016", "3-01-93", "14-4-1973", "22 Juin 2015", "Mama, I'm comin home!", "06/06/06" };
                foreach (var date in listOfDates)
                {
                     isValidDate = Validate(date, dateFormats);
                     Console.WriteLine("The string is, {0} and the date validity is {1}",date, isValidDate);
                }

               Console.ReadLine();

            }


            public static bool Validate(string s, string[] format)
            {

                DateTime frDt,enUDt, enGDt, enIDt ;


                bool fr,engU,engG, engI;

                   CultureInfo[] cis = { frc,usc,gbc,inc };
                    fr = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, cis[0], DateTimeStyles.None, out frDt);
                    engU = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, cis[1], DateTimeStyles.None, out enUDt);
                    engG = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, cis[2], DateTimeStyles.None, out enGDt);
                    engI = DateTime.TryParseExact(s, format, cis[3], DateTimeStyles.None, out enIDt);

                    if (fr || engU || engG||engI == true)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }         
                    return false;
            }


        }
```

Comment: The first string would be 10th day of the 23rd month of the year 2016, does that sound right to you?

Comment: Edited the question now. It's actually of MM-dd-yyyy format,
October 23, 2016.

Comment: Okay, Editting the questikn doesn't change the fact that you never actually account for that format in your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first date string is 10-23-2016

23 is not a valid month.  So dd-MM-yyyy will fail.